# Power series representation of $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{(x-2)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am working on a power series representation from Stewart's book (an old edition). I am asked to find the power series representation of

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{x^3}{(x-2)^2}
\end{align*}

I would like to know if I am on the right track, and/or if my answer is correct. It follows.

**My answer**

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x} &= 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n\\
\frac{1}{1-(-x+3)} &= 1 + (-x+3) + (-x+3)^2 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x+3)^n\\
\frac{1}{x-2} &= 1 + (-x+3) + (-x+3)^2 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x+3)^n
\end{align*}

Differentiating both sides,

\begin{align*}
\frac{-1}{(x-2)^2} &= -1 +2 (-x+3)(-1) -3 (-x+3)^2 (-1) + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -n \cdot (-x+3)^{n-1}\\
\frac{1}{(x-2)^2} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \cdot (-x+3)^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Multiplying both sides by $x^3$,

\begin{align*}
x^3 \cdot \frac{1}{(x-2)^2} &= x^3 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \cdot (-x+3)^{n-1}\\
\frac{x^3}{(x-2)^2} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \cdot x^3 \cdot  (-x+3)^{n-1}
\end{align*}

Given we have the series, we may proceed to find the radius and interval of convergence:

\begin{align*}
a_n &= n \cdot x^3 \cdot  (-x+3)^{n-1} \quad a_{n+1} = (n+1) \cdot x^3 \cdot  (-x+3)^{n} \quad \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)(-x+3)}{n}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\vert &= \vert -x+3 \vert
\end{align*}

So we find that $R = 1$ and $I = ]2,4[$

(I'll still work on the "edges" of the interval).

Can someone please verify what I've calculated?

Comment: Any range is given on $x$ ?  Because the geometric sum works if $(-x+3)\le 1$..

Comment: Hi Qwerty. No, no range is given.

Comment: If not range or pivot point is given, why did you decide to give a power series about the point $\;x=3\;$ ?? Why not around $\;x=2,\,\frac12\;$ or something else?

Comment: Well, let's say that I started with the $x^n$ series and worked my way with it. Would you suggest otherwise @DonAntonio?

Comment: For example$$\frac1{x-2}=-\frac12\frac1{1-\frac x2}=-\frac12\left(1+\frac x2+\frac{x^2}4+\ldots\right)\;,\;\;etc.$$

Comment: @DonAntonio so

$$\frac{x^3}{(x-2)^2}  =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+3}}{2^n}$$

is that correct?

Comment: @bru I don't think so...observe that for $\;x=-1\;$ we get different values in both sides: on the left, $\;-1/9\;$ , and on the right $$-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac12\right)^n=-\frac13$$ ...or in what range did you mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry I forgot to differentiate the right side. What I actually get is

$$\frac{x^3}{(x-2)^2} = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{n+2}}{2^{n}}$$

(but still for $x = -1$ the equation doesn't check, something must be off)

Comment: Actually for$$\frac{x^3}{(x-2)^2} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n \cdot x^{n+2}}{2^{n}}$$ it does check!